# Intellij вывод в консоль вопросительные знаки вместо русских букв. Данные получает из PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea, консоль, кириллица

Intellij Idea Console у меня вывод русские буквы нормально. Но вот когда я вывожу данные на русском, которые взял из базы данных сделанной на PostgreSQL я получаю вот что:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55764', transport: 'socket'
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@46daef40
�������� ������
�������� ����������� �����������
�������� ����������� ����������������
�������� ����������� ������������
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55764', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Собственно сам код:

```java
try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Lab1?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=windows-1251";
    Properties autorization = new Properties();
    autorization.put("user","postgres");
    autorization.put("password","k3st1bnx");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,autorization);
} catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error");
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

if (connection !=null)
    System.out.println(connection);
else
    System.out.println("Null!");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
String SQL = "select * from symptoms order by sickid";
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(SQL);

while (result.next()) {
    System.out.println(result.getString(2))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нажми file-cinsole в настройках проекта
везде ставь utf-8

Comment: Поставил windows-1251 и заработало

Answer (score 0):

Вот эта строчка как-то нелогично выглядит.

`useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=windows-1251`

Попробуйте вместо "windows-1251" указать "UTF-8"

И очень желательно проверить чтобы кодировка для вашей таблицы так же стояла UTF-8. И чтобы данные туда были записаны тоже в формате UTF-8

Comment: В глобальной кодировке поставил Windows-1251 и все заработало